# Can't catch exception IndexError in Python?

Tags: python, exception

This is the error I want to catch:

```
 Traceback:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/opt/django/fileupload/views.py" in upload_file
      56.         folder_info = url.split(':')[1] #Extracts folder info to use in the header

    Exception Type: IndexError at /upload_file/
    Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Tried using:

```
except (socket.error, paramiko.AuthenticationException, IndexError):
            return render_to_response('reform.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But it doesn't work.

I am able to catch the `socket.error` and `paramiko.Authentication` exceptions but not the `IndexError`. I am trying to catch the exception in Django. Thanks.

**Edit**:
Entire try and except block:

```
try:        
    source = str(username) + "@" + url #Source to list all the files
    add_key = str(username) + "@" + test_url
    add_known_hosts(password, add_key) #Add to the known hosts
    test_ssh(test_url, username, password) #Test Host_name, username and password
    destination = '/home/sachet/files'    
    command = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '--recursive', source],
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0] #sshpass needs to be installed into the server
    lines = (x.strip() for x in command.split('\n'))
    remote = [x.split(None, 4)[-1] for x in lines if x] #Removes permission from the file listing
    base_name = [os.path.basename(ok) for ok in remote]
    result = subprocess.Popen(['ls', destination], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].splitlines()

    return render_to_response('thanks.html', {'res1': remote, 'res': result, 'folder': folder_info}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
except (socket.error, paramiko.AuthenticationException, IndexError):
    return render_to_response('reform.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Can you please provide the full code that produces the traceback?  Your `except` block looks correct as demonstrated.

Comment: Post the entire `try-except` block.

Comment: What version of Python is it?

Comment: I have posted the entire try-except block. Other two exceptions catch beside IndexError is working.

Comment: The line in your exception doesn't appear in your code. This exception is being raised outside your try-block.

Comment: Look clearly. The Exception type is IndexError and I have raised the same exception. If my exception code is wrong it shouldn't have raised exception for other errors too.

Comment: `folder_info = url.split(':')[1]` That line does not appear to be in the code block you have posted. And, appears to be apart of Django itself. Could you get the stack trace if possible?

Comment: Are you sure the `IndexError` being raised by your fileupload.views module is actually the core `IndexError` and not some custom one, which you are not catching?

Comment: I believe it's a core IndexError. Anyway, how do I make sure?

Comment: Catch the error with `except Exception as e:` and then check the class of `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IndexError is not raised within the try/except block you posted. The IndexError is raised on the line where folder_info is assigned to (line 56 in views.py). You need to move that line of code into your try/except block in order to catch that error.

```
File "/opt/django/fileupload/views.py" in upload_file
    56.         folder_info = url.split(':')[1]  <-- This line
```

Or, better yet, put a separate try/except around the "folder = ..." line, just for the IndexError, to make the intention of your code clearer.

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks